# Use a batch file to write txt to another file

Tags: batch-file

How would i add this text to a file because it seems to get confused with the other greater than less than signs thanks

echo  >> C:\docs\thisdoc.txt

Comment: Windows or Linux? If Windows `echo your_message >> your_file` should work, appending message to file. If you want to rewrite your file use `echo your_message > your_file`

Answer (score 1):

If I've got you right, you want to write the text "echo >> c:\docs\thisdoc.txt" in a file? Then you need to escape the ">"characters with "^":

```
echo echo ^>^> C:\docs\thisdoc.txt > mybatch.cmd
```